# MongoDB - How to query and aggregate nested documents values

Tags: json, mongodb

I have the following **3** Json documents within a mongoDB collection:

```
  {
   'title': 'Best',
   'array'  : [
       {'name' :  '1',
        'value':  '2'
       },
       {'name' :  '3',
        'value':  '4'
       }


      ]

}
```

and :

```
   {
   'title': 'Best',
   'array'  : [
       {'name' :  '5',
        'value':  '6'
       },
       {'name' :  '7',
        'value':  '8'
       }
    ]
}
```

and:

```
  {
   'title': 'Worst',
   'array'  : [
       {'name' :  'Not_needed',
        'value':  'Not_needed'
       },
       {'name' :  'Not_needed',
        'value':  'Not_needed'
       }
    ]
}
```

I need a query that gives me:

```
{[
       {'name' :  '1',
        'value':  '2'
       },
       {'name' :  '3',
        'value':  '4'
       },
       {'name' :  '5',
        'value':  '6'
       },
       {'name' :  '7',
        'value':  '8'
       }
 ]}
```

How can I do that? Is that what people refer to as aggregation ? Could you please provide me with a mongoDB query for that?

Comment: what is the main concern? What query should do for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query using aggregation framework that nearly generates the document you want.

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
{ "$unwind": "$array" },
{ "$group": 
    { 
      "_id": "$title", 
      "array": {"$push": "$array"} 
    }
}, 
{ "$project": 
    { 
      "array": 1, 
      "_id": 0 
    } 
}
])
```

Comment: This pushes array as [], while I need its contents to be pushed as objects. Could you do that ?

Comment: Not sure that can be done. The contents are a set of documents/objects and are represented using arrays in JSON.